# Are Facebook Page Access Tokens temporary?

Tags: token, facebook-messenger

I am trying to determine if page access tokens used with the messenger api are permanent.  Seeing this code in one of their examples, which indicates to me that they are using the token as a constant value :

access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN

I get the Page Access Token shown on my facebook app dashboard in this way:
I log into facebook, go to developer.facebook.com, select my messenger app, then on the dashboard go to Products > Messenger > Settings and can select my page and then get a token.

Can I put that value in a properties file and then use it indefinitely with my application when getting/sending messages to and from the page?

I am getting a bit confused regarding the documentation around other tokens, like user tokens and login tokens vs. page tokens.

Editing to add that I am using the page access token in order to make a POST request to this url : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages in order to reply to a message sent to my page by a user.

Comment: If  my app webhook receives a message (to my fb page from a user), and wants to reply, is the user access token for the user fb account that the page is assoc with?  :  from the fb docs:  "These access tokens are similar to user access tokens, except that they provide permission to APIs that read, write or modify the data belonging to a Facebook Page. To obtain a page access token you need to start by obtaining a user access token and asking for the manage_pages permission. Once you have the user access token you then get the page access token via the Graph API."

Answer (score 1):

**Extended Page Tokens are valid forever.**

You need to use a User Token, extend the User Token and then get an Extended Page Token with the Extended User Token.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: I am confused as to why I need a user token to get an extended page token.  My use case is, a user writes a message to my page, my webhook code gets called, I post to reply to the user who sent the message to my page.   The user messaging my page never has to login, so i don't have any user token for them.  It seems I should just need a page token

Comment: Also, I am considering i need to get a new token each time I want to hit the API to send a reply, am I correct to assume I should do that since I never know when a token will expire?

Comment: that´s just how it is, a page token is tied to a specific user, with a specific user token. and again, extended page tokens are valid forever. you can´t get a new token all the time, because user (and page) tokens need user interaction, there is no way to auto-refresh or auto-generate them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @luschn.  From reading the links provided, I think I need to hit this url to get the token I need :   
 `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=[app-id]&client_secret=[app-secret]&fb_exchange_token=[short-lived-token]`     I am assuming the short-lived-token is the token for the user that is messaging the page I am working on.  What I am not sure of still is how to get that short lived token. The message I receive does have a user id, but not a token, looking for a url to use to grab that users token . . .

Comment: I am writing code that gets this json message when a user sends a message to my fb page :  `{
 "object": "page",
 "entry": [{
  "id": "123",     
  "time": 1507689291087,
  "messaging": [{
   "sender": {
    "id": "456"
   },
   "recipient": {
    "id": "789"
   },
   "timestamp": 1507689290469,
   "message": {
    "mid": "mid.$abcdefg",
    "seq": 2,
    "text": "Hello World"
   }
  }]
 }]
}`   is one of the id's in that message I received what I can use to get the user token?  I am looking for a url like graph.facebook.com/userId to get the token back for the user

Comment: why would you need a user token? i am talking about the user token of the app admin. get it extended, get a page token with the extended one and store it on the server code. that´s all, no other user token needed...you create it ONE time only with YOUR account. how to get a user token is explained in the docs, you just need to implement login or use the api explorer.

Comment: Ahhh ok, thank you very much, that's where my confusion was, when you said I needed a user token in your answer, I thought I needed a token for the user that was messaging the page.  Now I get it.   Thank you again for taking the time to reply.

Comment: you are welcome. would be nice if you could accept my answer for my efforts - and after all, it is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have solved this and wanted to post in case anyone else had the same confusion.

I assumed I needed to make a GET request to a facebook url in my code to get a new token before each Request to GET or POST to the messenger API.  Using the information in the links above, I learned how to get an extended token here:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/<my app id here>?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts&version=v2.10
```

I then can use that ID indefinitely as it is supposed to not expire.  I am going to assume it is OK to put this id into my properties file, if anyone has opinions on a better place to store this token value I would be interested.

Comment: take a look at my answer, it covers everything you need to know. the two links in the answer (one is from the official docs) explain very well how to generate different tokens, and you need an extended page token. one time. not for every user.